if P≠NP then does P ≠ coNP?
If P ≠ NP then does P ≠ coNP?
If so please explain why?
I have tried thinking about subsets between langauges, but not sure where to start.

Think about the contrapositive.

This is a classic text book exercise. Think about the hint given by @Li-yaoXia. A similar question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442086/if-p-np-then-np-conp-why-is-this-so
